# Regex removing all digits/numbers for GA filter

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm sad, i get nowhere with this regex. Regarding a following strings;

**Regex**:

```
(\/company\/ttext\/)((\d{9,10}\/?)+)((\D\/?)*)((\w?\d{9,14}\/?)*)
```

**URL targeting**:

1. /company/ttext/123450926
2. /company/ttext/123450393/text2
3. /company/ttext/123400060/text2/anothertext#/account/5560789751/1234229821
4. /company/ttext/123400060/1234525692/someteext/some-text/text3/46730990136
5. /company/ttext/123453150/4212780820/text/some-text/som-etext/123412341067430

The idea is to be able to filter out numberstrings that are 9-14 chars long in a GA filter. And where my idea was to do the regex in groups to be able to
Where the twist goes. Needs to be in a parenthesis so that i can filter the groups that contain text. As GA-filter example below.

```
Field A: Request URI (.*)([^/])?(.*)
Output: Request URI $A1$A2/?$A3
```

Comments on my regex,(/company/ttext/)((\d{9,10}/?)+)((\D/?)*)((\w?\d{9,14}/?)*)

- First text group
- second, find one or more numberstrings
- third, find a string that is non-digit and is 0 or more instances
- four, find 0 or more numberstrings ,can contain a letter and digits between 9-14.

This might be the complete wrong approach, and I gladly take any input you guys have :)

Comment: It is unclear what you want to match. Try [`^(\/company\/ttext\/)(\d{9,10})\/?(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/aI4yX9/2).

Comment: Oh sorry for not making it clear. I want to target all digits, but to make it a GA filter (advanced custom filter), i need to group them, to be able to remove some of them in later stage.

And i did my regex like that since the 9-14 digitstring can appear both in end and within the URI.

Comment: You could make it clearer if you added expected output structure for each input URL you provided in the question. Note that there is ni way to retrieve all the captured strings matched with a quantified group (I.e. `(?:(\w+)\s+)+` won't let you extract all the words having spaces after them).

Comment: Hmm, ok. It seems like it wont work, now when i tried to map out the expected result.

How would you go about the original issue 

"Remove all (numberstrings 9-14 in sequence) in GA. The number sequence as you can see can appear in different places of the URL"